# Checking if the element is on screen with assert, NoSuchElementException occured

Tags: java, selenium, appium, assert

I'm trying to check if an element is on screen by using assert function.
I'm using Appium and Java to my test application (AndroidDriver).
What I expect is return 1 if the element is on screen or 0 for it is not. 
When I try this;

```
assert driver.findElementById("com.tmob.AveaOIM:id/layout_ayarlar_ovit").isDisplayed() : "It is not on the screen";
```

isDisplayed() is a boolean function but it isn't work because of

> NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page
>   using the given search parameters.

How can i check this element with assert?

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code:

```
driver.findElementById("layout_ayarlar_ovit").isDisplayed()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and used this as work around

I would suggest you should use page factory 
put this as a constructor

public constructorName() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);}

@FindBy(xpath="//")

private WebElement anyName;

if(anyname.isDisplayed){

System.out.println("Element is present");
}

Answer (score 0):

Assign the return value in isTrue variable (or name of your preference ) and in next line use assert with message :

boolean isTrue=driver.findElementById("com.tmob.AveaOIM:id/layout_ayarlar_ovit").isDisplayed();
Assert.assertTrue(true,isTrue, "Failed to locate element") ;

If assert fails, output will be "Failed to locate element" 
If assert pass , test will continue to next line.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("com.tmob.AveaOIM:id/layout_ayarlar_ovit"));
}catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
  Assert.fail("Error on Page:element not found");
}
Assert.assertTrue(  driver.findElement(By.xpath("com.tmob.AveaOIM:id/layout_ayarlar_ovit")).isDisplayed());
```